# How to encode an url into into a 60-bit 01 string? (word2vec)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, natural-language, word-embeddings

> At the same time, we counted the frequency of occurrences of
> characters in all URLs in the dataset and selected the first 59
> characters with the highest frequency as valid characters. It contains
> 26 English letters, 10 Arabic numerals, and 23 special characters
> including “@/: = #-.” Other characters that are not in the list are
> all “special characters,” and each URL is treated as a sequence of
> only 60 different characters. As shown in Figure 3, each character is
> encoded into a 60-bit 01 string where one in the interface value row
> and zero in the rest. Then, we use the word2vec method in natural
> language processing to encode the previously processed 60-bit 01
> string into a 64-bit word vector.

I counted the frequency of occurrences of chars in all URLs and I selected the first 59 chars. How can I treat an URL (255 chars, filled up with zeros) as a sequence of only 60 different chars?

Link to paper: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/scn/2019/2595794

Comment: The explanation is hard to follow, but I think the intended meaning is that each of the selected the 59 characters are represented as 1-hot vectors, so a single URL is the collection of all of the 1-hot vectors that appear in the URL string.

Comment: @Sycorax That's very nearly so: in addition, all other characters besides those 59 were lumped into a single category termed "special character," yielding a reduced alphabet of 60 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comments into an answer:

- Each character of a URL is represented as a binary vector, with a 1 to indicate the letter and 0 otherwise. This is commonly called "one-hot encoding."
- The vector has only 60 digits.
- Only the 59 most common characters have a bit designated for them in particular.
- The remaining characters are termed "special characters," and grouped together in the 60th position.

Comment: What do mean by "grouped together in the 60th position"? Can you give me an example? The [solution](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/IAjTzFQNFKM) that I currently have, gives me an error when a char is not in the alphabet!

Comment: Here's a simplified example. Suppose you have the domain `abcdef.com` and your alphabet is `abc`. Then `a` is encoded as `1000`, `b` is encoded as `0100` and `c` is `0010`. But `d`, `e`, and `f` are all encoded as `0001` because they're not in the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you very much!